# Calling a command line in MONO on MAC OS X

Tags: macos, mono

I want to be able to call the automator or unix commands like ls from a mono app and ge the results back.

This can be accomplished on windows easily. The question is how is this done on the mac??

Comment: it had the mono sample. which is the same for windowss. I am still unsure what is the same and what is different. please make this answer so i mark it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

caveat: I've never written a char of mono in my life.

I imagine it's a matter of redirecting stdout and firing up a process. this [linux forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=320322) shows that you can do pretty much that - OSX will behave mostly as a UNIX-like system for you, I reckon.

Oh by the way, if you want to fire up an OSX application, have a dig around inside the ".app" bundle. OSX shows these as a file, but they're actually directories. In the finder you can right-mouse click and "show package contents", or you can open up a terminal / command prompt and `cd` into them. For instance, you can launch the Automator like this from the terminal:

```
/Applications/Automator.app/Contents/MacOS/Automator
```

I don't know if you would want to go down this route, but if you're going to be interfacing with OSX (gui) apps, you might want to look at using [Applescript](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html) as some "glue" between Mono and the app.